# Binding SelectedItem vs SelectedIndex - When should I choose one over the other?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Let's say that you have an observable collection of object type Foo, and you have a custom ListView that the user will select from.

Your bound data object:

```
// property with getter / setter / INotifyPropertyChanged
ObservableCollection<Foo> MyCollection;
```

In XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding MyCollection} />
```

Is it more appropriate to bind to the SelectedIndex in XAML and create the following in your data object:

```
int SelectedIndex { get; set; } // also raising property changed notifications
Foo SelectedObject
{
   get { return MyCollection[SelectedIndex]; }
}
```

Or to create this and bind to the SelectedItem in XAML:

```
Foo SelectedObject { get; set; } // also raising property changed notifications
```

And why?

Comment: According to this website's [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help), it is *not* here to find out any *best practices*,or to *discuss* anything and so your question is clearly [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As such, I have voted to close it. For my 2 cents worth, I'd always recommend using the `SelectedItem` method, but it really depends on you. Use one, then if you don't like it, use the other instead.

Comment: @Sheridan My understanding was that most "What's the best way for X"  questions are too broad which is why they get closed, but a specific question like this of which method to use over the other and why seems like it'd be prefectly on-topic for the site. In fact, it's an answer I'm interested in as well. If you think the words "Best practice" in the title will lead to more close votes, perhaps we can edit them out and replace them with some thing more specific, such as *"Is there a difference between using SelectedItem or SelectedIndex, and when should I choose one over the other?"*

Comment: @Rachel I completely agree, this maybe shouldn't be "best practice" but "which way is better"...

Comment: @Sheridan, do you have a problem with the question or the title?  Where in the world wide web would I post such a question?

Comment: @Rachel, in my experience with these 'Best Practice' questions is that they are *Primarily opinion based*... *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* This is also shown by the opposing answers that the question author has received so far. And Arthur, I don't have any problem... I'm just following the guidelines of this website, as should we all. Despite your edit, your question is still *primarily opinion based*.

Comment: @Sheridan - I disagree.  I would say, as Athari pointed out, that there are non-opinion based reasons to use one method over the other.  I understand they don't want general opinion questions posted, but I as do other users feel this is a useful question.  Also, it was Rachel's edit, not mine.  How exactly did you come to the conclusion this was "clearly off topic" where there is no "clear" mention of this question being "off topic"

Comment: *other users feel this is a useful question*... that's the beauty of this website - it's community driven. If other users feel that I have stuck to the guidelines too rigidly, they won't vote to close your question. As questions need 5 close votes before they get closed (and even then can be voted to be reopened), you really need not worry about receiving a single close vote. Even if your question was closed by the community, you could just as easily get your answer from all of the practically identical questions that have  already been asked here before.

Comment: @Sheridan - Do you have a link to these "practically identical questions" ?

Comment: You would have been shown a list before you wrote your question, but you can find plenty more [on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=Binding+SelectedItem+vs+SelectedIndex+).

Comment: Here's a good link for you @Sheridan: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271863/misuse-of-off-topic-closure-reason?cb=1

Comment: Why is that supposed to be a good link?.. it has very little relation to this situation. In my opinion, your question is *clearly* opinion based. There is no single correct answer. In the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) page of the Help Center, it says *To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where... • every answer is equally valid... • there is no actual problem to be solved*. It's a shame that you've taken this all so personally. I didn't write these guidelines, I just follow

Comment: On the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page of the Help Center, it says *if your question generally covers... • a specific programming problem, or • a software algorithm, or • software tools commonly used by programmers; and is • a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!* Your question covers none of this. It continues *Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be put on hold by the community until they are improved.*

Comment: @Sheridan - The guidelines say to avoid having extended discussions in the comments.  I want to follow the guidelines and not continue our conversation here.  I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Let's be clear... I was happy to end this conversation after explaining that I had voted to close your question, but *you* kept going on and on and on and on... and on again just 10 minutes ago. If you're now finished, then I am also happy to end this conversation here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both cases are acceptable, however which you choose usually depends on the design of your data models, and which method would require the least amount of code to get working.

A few rules I use to determine which one to select

1. If `SelectedObject` cannot be null (such as an enum), and you need to default to be no item selected, then use `SelectedIndex`.
2. If `SelectedObject` may not be considered `.Equals()` to any item in your `Items` list, use `SelectedIndex`. This is because `SelectedItem` compares objects with the `Items` collection using `.Equals()`, so a reference comparism will return false which will result in your object not becomming selected.

   This usually happens when your selected item comes from a different location than where your list of items is. For example, one database calls to load the `Items` for the list, and a separate database call obtaining an object that includes a `SelectedObject` property.
3. If you need to reference only one of `SelectedObject` or `SelectedIndex` in other parts of your code, use that one.
4. If your data models already have a `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedObject` property, then use that.
5. If all other things are equal, I use a `SelectedObject` property to bind the `SelectedItem` property.

   This is because to me it makes more sense to refer to something like `SelectedUser` instead of `SelectedUserIndex` in the code behind, and I prefer to avoid looking up the item in the collection anytime I want to do something with the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your needs. If you need to *set* the selected item, you need the second version. If you need the selected item's *index*, you need the first version. If you need neither, it's up to your personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are fine. Use the one you find easier to use. I don't find myself relying on indices often, but your cases may be different.

If you look at MVVM libraries, Caliburn.Micro, for example, expects you to use `SelectedObject` approach. It explicitly supports this convention.

And note on collection properties. In general, it's better idea to have read-only auto-properties and set them in constructor (property change notification won't be necessary). It is not advised to change instances of collections. While WPF supports it, it's much easier to subsribe to collection events in your own code if the instance doesn't change.

Comment: How does Caliburn.Micro expect usage of the SelectedObject approach?  It seems it could be done just as simply either way.

Comment: Another thing I use to help me decide which method to use is if the `SelectedObject` will always point to the reference of an object in the list of items. For example, in some cases I'll obtain my list of items from one database call, and my selected item comes from a different database call. In these cases, if the two objects are not considered equal then using `SelectedObject` will not work, so I often use `SelectedIndex` rather than overwriting the `.Equals()` method on the object. But for the most part I prefer `SelectedItem` to `SelectedIndex`

Comment: @KingArthur `x:Name="Foos"` turns into `ItemsSource={Binding Foos} SelectedItem={Binding SelectedFoo}`, iirc. Is `SelectedIndex` supported this way?

Comment: Yes, you could instead set ItemsSource={Binding Foos} SelectedIndex={Binding MyFoosIndex}, and create a MyFoosIndex property on an object inheriting from the PropertyChangedBase class  from CM.Micro, which would effectively be the same.

Comment: @KingArthur You're talking about explicit binding, I'm talking about convention based binding. [Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ConventionManager.cs](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/e82bc5a641485033dd4b94ea7b71cb115636e30c/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ConventionManager.cs) — I don't see support for `Selected*Index` property convention.

Comment: @Athari sorry, I didn't realize you meant implicit binding.  You are right, it is to the SelectedObject property.

Answer (score 0):

I personal think bind to the SelectedObject is much cleaner unless you need access to the SelectedIndex

The only time I use SelectedIndex is when I want to set a default value of 0 to select the first item.